# Animate NavigationBar à la pushViewController w/o changing the viewController

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I have a `viewController` showing an `UIWebView`. Inside of that `UIWebView` I have a Sencha Touch App running. On top of that `UIWebView` sits the native `UINavigationBar` (not Sencha Touch).

Inside the Sencha Touch App, the user can switch the screens back and forth. Sencha Touch animates those switches, as they would be if I had called `pushViewController` in my native app.

Of course those animations coming from my Sencha Touch App don't change the native `UINavigationBar`. I can manually change the left/rightBarButtonItems and the `navigationitem.title`. But I would like those changes to be animated as if I would have called `pushViewController`.

Is there any way to get those animations on the `UINavigationBar` without actually changing or animating the `UIWebView`? Any idea's pointing me in the right direction how to achieve that would be well appreciated…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `pushNavigationItem:animated` method of `UINavigationBar`? You can create instances on `UINavigationItem` and keep pushing and popping them from navigation bar as you like. `UINavigationItem` also has `title` property which will take care of navigation titles and `back` buttons.

Read this for more details:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Comment: Looks like it could be useful for me. First problem is `Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.`
Maybe I can hide the controlled UINavigationBar and create my own on that ViewController. Will take some time to play with that idea...

Comment: Since you are going to control the navigation bar yourself, just don't use a `UINavigationController` at all. Resize your view such that it takes a navigation bar into account, and put your own instance of the bar at the top. This will save you from hiding the navigation bar. If you do have some some other use of navigation controller, then you wouldn't have that option.

Comment: I'm developing a hybrid app with many more views than just the one which shows the Sencha Touch App. I definitely want to use a UINavigationController. But hiding the controlled UINavigationBar and showing my own on that single ViewControlle already works. Thx a lot for pointing me to the possibility of using a stand-alone UINavigationBar.